# Protecting and hiding sheets in WorkbookOpen disables the screen

Tags: vba, excel

I have a routine that is called from the WorkbookOpen event - all it does is hide/unhide the appropriate sheets and protect some of them (I'll put the code below), and it causes an odd problem where there is a picture of the spreadsheet on the screen but anything I do selecting cells, changing values, etc. IS happening to the sheet but is not being shown on the screen - also the sheet tabs are not visible at the bottom.

If I click the close button and then cancel, in the box that asks if I want to save... all my changes are there, the sheet tabs are visible and Excel is working as it should (there is no WorkbookBeforeSave routine, so no code is triggered there)

I'd love to know what's causing this (or even a workaround) as it is driving me nuts.

The code that is called by the Open event is:

```
Sub ProtectAndHide()
Dim xSheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case UCase(xSheet.Codename)
            Case "PROPERTIES", "COA", "ASSUMPTIONS", "ENGINE", "EXECSUMM", "NOTES", "DISCLAIMER", "COVER"
                xSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                xSheet.Protect Password:=HIDDEN.Range("iWord")
            Case "COAMAP", "SLDEPN"
                xSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                xSheet.Protect Password:=HIDDEN.Range("iWord")
            Case "HIDDEN", "REPSHEET", "CONTENTSSHEET", "ACTIONS"
                xSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End Select
    Next xSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove/comment  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' line

Answer (score 2):

Add `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

```
  Sub ProtectAndHide()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Select Case UCase(xSheet.Codename)
                Case "PROPERTIES", "COA", "ASSUMPTIONS", "ENGINE", "EXECSUMM", "NOTES", "DISCLAIMER", "COVER"
                    xSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                    xSheet.Protect Password:=HIDDEN.Range("iWord")
                Case "COAMAP", "SLDEPN"
                    xSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                    xSheet.Protect Password:=HIDDEN.Range("iWord")
                Case "HIDDEN", "REPSHEET", "CONTENTSSHEET", "ACTIONS"
                    xSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End Select
        Next xSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```